# What will be the sollution if

Tags: number-theory

> $$\begin{align*} 7&=7 \\ 7\cdot7&=49 \\ 7\cdot7\cdot7&=343 \\ 7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7&=2041\end{align*}$$
>   What will be the last digit if $111$ number of $7$s are multiplied?

Comment: So you want $7^{111} \bmod 10$. Observe $7$ and $10$ are coprime so you can use Euler's totient theorem. Use this and conclude accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean the last digit?

Comment: You don't need much fancy math. Do you a few more until it gets periodic.

Comment: Without making the full calculation, what will be the unit digit of the next term, $7^5=7\cdot 7\cdot 7\cdot 7\cdot 7$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just touching on the hint that I gave you in the comments:

Since $7$ and $10$ have greatest common divisor $1$; we have $7^{\phi(10)}\equiv 1\bmod 10$, that is $7^{4}\equiv1\bmod 10$. Then $$(7^{4})^{27}=7^{108}\equiv1\bmod10\Rightarrow7^{111}=7^{108}\cdot7^{3}=7^{3}\equiv3\bmod10.$$

Alternatively, brute force for a few terms will give that the powers of $7$ have last digit following a periodic pattern of $7,9,3,1$. Since $111$ is $3\bmod 4$; it follows that the last digit will be $3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$7^1={\bf 7} \qquad 7^5=1680{\bf 7}  \\
7^2=4{\bf 9} \qquad 7^6=11764{\bf 9}\\
7^3=34{\bf 3} \qquad ...\\
7^4=204{\bf 1} \qquad ...\\
$$